# android annotations @Receiver

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do broadcast receiver using android annotations library with it's two ways but the ide doesn't recognize @Receiver or @ReceiverAction as on this code

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.EReceiver;

/**
 * Created by M.Hemdan on 11/12/2014.
 */
@EReceiver
public class MyBroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @ReceiverAction(actions = android.content.Intent.VIEW, dataSchemes = "http")
    protected void onHttp() {
        // Will be called when an App wants to open a http website but not for https.
    }

    @ReceiverAction(actions = android.content.Intent.VIEW, dataSchemes = {"http", "https"})
    protected void onHttps() {
        // Will be called when an App wants to open a http or https website.
    }
}
```

then on activity if I try the other way

```
  @Receiver(actions = android.content.Intent.VIEW, dataSchemes = "http")
protected void onHttp() {
    // Will be called when an App wants to open a http website but not for https.
}

@Receiver(actions = android.content.Intent.VIEW, dataSchemes = {"http", "https"})
protected void onHttps() {
    // Will be called when an App wants to open a http or https website.
}
```

and this is the error which appear to me [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the annotation classes you're using.

For example, add

```
import org.androidannotations.annotations.Receiver;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ReceiverAction;
```

Comment: Valid import can't recognize them

Comment: @laalto is right, you have to add the imports. If they cannot be recognized, that means our API jar is not in your classpath. From the build log, i assume you use gradle. Please add the dependencies correctly as we describe that [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle).